# Change the default upload file path for a content type

Tags: files

The default file upload path used by Drupal is sites/default/files.

How can the default path be changed for a content type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public filesystem is a system-wide setting; it can't be different per content type.

There's a setting under every file field attached to your content types that will allow you to choose the sub-folder within public:// that files for that field are uploaded to.

As an extension you can get a more advanced version of that functionality with the [File (Field) Paths](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module...but beware, there are issues with it and you'll need to test thoroughly before deploying to a live site.

One of those methods will likely be your best bet. There's lots more info at [Working with Files in Drupal](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file), including documentation on how to use the private file system (in case you can leverage that).